# Big-Oh notation for a single while loop covering two halves of an array with two iterator vars

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Trying to brush up on my Big-O understanding for a test (A very basic Big-O understanding required obviously) I have coming up and was doing some practice problems in my book.

They gave me the following snippet

```
public static void swap(int[] a)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length-1;

    while (i < j)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Pretty easy to understand I think. It has two iterators each covering half the array with a fixed amount of work (which I think clocks them both at O(n/2))

Therefore O(n/2) + O(n/2) = O(2n/2) = O(n)

Now please forgive as this is my current understanding and that was my attempt at the solution to the problem. I have found many examples of big-o online but none that are quite like this where the iterators both increment and modify the array at basically the same time.

The fact that it has one loop is making me think it's O(n) anyway.

Would anyone mind clearing this up for me?

Thanks

Comment: FYI: even if you only iterate over half an array - something like `sumOddIndexElements()`, for example - it's still O(n). The constant factor of 1/2 goes away. When you start analyzing more complex algorithms, it's helpful to switch from exact counts to big-O early in the analysis. Then your intermediate steps become simpler because you can throw away terms. I.E. if a subroutine does O(n) + O(log n) work, you can immediately reduce it to O(n) for the rest of the analysis.

Comment: @japreiss I'm sorry, not trying to be redundant by any means but your last sentence confused me a bit. If I understand correctly, O(log n) will become insignificant enough to O(n) at a certain point that it is not worth calculating into the time efficiency and therefore we drop it?

Comment: By the definition of big O, when you add terms you can always drop everything but the asymptotically largest. You can prove that `n + log n < 2n` but `2n` is O(n). So yes, it's insignificant, in a very well defined way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The fact that it has one loop is making me think it's O(n) anyway.

This is correct. Not because it is making one loop, but because it is one loop that depends on the size of the array by a constant factor: the big-O notation ignores any constant factor. `O(n)` means that the only influence on the algorithm is based on the size of the array. That it actually takes half that time, does not matter for big-O.

In other words: if your algorithm takes time `n+X`, `Xn`, `Xn + Y` will all come down to big-O `O(n)`.

It gets different if the size of the loop is changed other than a constant factor, but as a logarithmic or exponential function of `n`, for instance if size is `100` and loop is `2`, size is `1000` and loop is `3`, size is `10000` and loop is `4`. In that case, it would be, for instance, `O(log(n))`.

It would also be different if the loop is independent of size. I.e., if you would always loop `100` times, regardless of loop size, your algorithm would be `O(1)` (i.e., operate in some constant time).

> *I was also wondering if the equation I came up with to get there was somewhere in the ballpark of being correct.*

Yes. In fact, if your equation ends up being some form of `n * C + Y`, where `C` is some constant and `Y` is some other value, the result is `O(n)`, regardless of whether see is greater than `1`, or smaller than `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also wondering if the equation I came up with to get there was somewhere in the ballpark of being correct. It helps to think about it mathematically like that but I am taking a shot in the dark with it. Some validation on that particular aspect would be great. I'm assuming it's either `O(n/2) + O(n/2) or just O(n/2) and then I ignore the /2 alltogether`

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the loop. Loop will determine the Big O. But the loop runs only for half the array.

So its. **2 +  6 *(n/2)**

If we make n very large, other numbers are really small. So they won't matter.
So its O(n).

Lets say you are running 2 separate loops. **2 + 6* (n/2) + 6*(n/2)** . In that case it will be O(n) again.

But if we run a nested loop. **2+ 6*(n*n)**. Then It will be O(n^2)

Always remove the constants and do the math. You got the idea.

Comment: So let me break that down really quick. It's 2 initial operations + 6 operations for every iteration times the total iterations?

Comment: Your example with `O(2n)` still ends up as `O(n)`, because it is still singly dependent on size. Otherwise, if two loops with yield a different result, half a loop should also yield a different result in big-O notation.

Comment: Right, my mistake. 2 again is a constant. That won't matter. If the number is very large.

Comment: Well, is 2+6(n/2) really that great of an estimate? I thought that the break in linearity is the bottleneck and therefore the algorithm O(n/2), depending on the number of jumps/forks. For O it won't matter but in general for estimates.

Comment: The constant 6 isn't really appropriate as you don't know the execution times of the individual operations, which are machine dependent. You could base your reasoning on the number of variable assignments, which is indisputably 5 per iteration (`i++` is short for `i+= 1`).

Comment: What about i<j checking? One unit of work is assigned for each operation. Since we are calculating O(n), we need not bother about execution times. I see 6 operations in the loop. So 6 units of work.

Comment: Not all work units take the same time, so 6 is meaningless and misleading, adding apples and pears. In practice, the time for a test+conditional jump wildly differs from that of a data move. It is enough to say "a bounded number of constant-time operations".

Comment: I get the point. 6 is just for illustration. That is what I learned in school.

Answer (score 0):

As `j-i` decreases by `2` units on each iteration, `N/2` of them are taken (assuming `N=length(a)`).

Hence the running time is indeed `O(N/2)`. And `O(N/2)` is strictly equivalent to `O(N)`.